# Is it worth implementing a server for binary communications

Tags: http, tcp, binary

I need to implement a communication between two remote modules/programs. The client sends an image and the server responds with another image. The communication must be really fast and the server must be reliable. Several clients shall send many requests (pictures) per second at the same time.

I would like to know educated opinions. Now, my questions are:
1* TCP or HTTP?

2* Would you implement the server (opening the pool of sockets and so on), or would you better rely on a good and mature server (like a Tomcat) that handles the communication so you can just focus on the logic that you deploy the server?

I'm almost determined to go for a mature server and HTTP but I would like to read hints and possible pitfalls.

Thank you so much. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

A dedicated server will be faster and use less resources.  However, it will take somewhat longer to implement.  Using an HTTP webserver means conforming to the spec (TCP is just raw data) but you can find a library for that.

Unless I knew that performance was to be an immediate issue, I'd go with the existing server/library solution.  Keep it modular and you can always replace the communication module at a future date if you do need improved performance.

Comment: UDP transport can be even faster (in terms of raw performance) but it will make implementation more complex.

Comment: @VadymStetsiak Why would UDP be faster?

Comment: UDP avoids the initial 3-way handshake of TCP.  It is also packet-based and so you don't have to parse a stream.  However, there is no guaranteed delivery and packets are limited to 64kB (though more than 1500 bytes -- the typical MTU -- is not recommended).

Comment: @BrianWhite additionally UDP does not wait for ACK messages and does not have transmission control (sliding window, Nagle algorithm etc). Those things make UDP way faster then TCP but at a price of guaranteed delivery and streaming.

Comment: @VadymStetsiak, actually, none of those things make TCP slower.  Or to be specific: they make for limits on throughput but do not increase latency.  On the other hand, TCP does measurements that allow it to make the most of the connection available whereas with UDP you can only guess... meaning that,  when you care about reliable delivery, you can actually get higher throughput with TCP than UDP.